# Android Kotlin button listener

Tags: android, kotlin, button

I have a kotlin Tetris code. It is working but ,i want to modify left and right buttons code.Normally i press code and figures move one field. i want to hold down button and figure must go end of the field .
Sorry my level of English . I hope i can explain my problem. thanks for help

```
    right_button.setOnClickListener {
        if (globalY + figure.last().second !in (0 until yCellCount) || globalX + figure.getRightXIndex() == xCellCount - 1 ||  isRightCellFilled())
            return@setOnClickListener
        else {
            clearFieldFromFigure()
            globalX++
            nextDropSetter()
            drawFigure()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use right_button.setOnLongClickListener

Comment: I used but nothing happened.  Actually long click must be used , but this functions must have loop .
I want the figure to move as long as the button is pressed. My aim is to stop the figure when I get my hand down from the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with this information:

.setOnClickListener listens for clicks, not being pressed down so you will have to use another listener to determine when it is being held down.

For left and right buttons, you will need to set up a time delay when it is being held down unless when you hold it down it will just fly to one end. I'd recommended moving it when it is touched and then every half second(or whatever you want) the button is held down.

To do that correctly you need knowledge of Coroutines to avoid blocking the main thread while stalling.

I hope I opened your mind to google searches you can do to help you figure out your issue.

Comment: yes, that was exactly what I wanted to explain.
but i'm new to android programming.
Can you give a simple and brief example.